# How to Knit a Rmarkdown file into different directory in a R project

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio, knitr, working-directory

**How can I set a specific output directory without changing my working/project directory when I knit the file?**

I am trying to knit an output (html or word doc) from my rmd file into a directory that is different than where my rmd file locates. I already have an R project to control the root directory.

The folder has following structure:

**a_folder**:

- `a_project.Rproj`
- program/

  - `data_summary.rmd`
  - `data_summary.html`
- report/

I want `data_summary.html` to be generated into the folder report/ when I knit `data_summary.rmd` but working directory remains the same.

I have tried to use the following YAML header. It dose knit into report folder, however, it changed my original working directory `"a_folder"` to `"a_folder/program"` when I knit it.

```
knit: (function(inputFile, encoding) {
  rmarkdown::render(inputFile, encoding = encoding, output_dir = "report") })
```

Comment: Even without that particular YAML header, wouldn't the working directory be `"a_folder/program"` by default since that's where your rmd file is located? [Source](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/working-directory.html)

Comment: No, the working directory should be "a_folder" because that's where the Rproj is.

Comment: The `rmarkdown::render()` function have a `knit_root_dir` argument, maybe try change this.

Comment: `rmarkdown::render()` will require creating a new R script to run my rmd file, which I don't think it's optimal.